# Redirect w output to a file

Tags: linux, bash

How do I redirect the `w` output to a file in `$DATE` named `$TIME.users`?

I have this but not sure it works:

```
w > $TIME.users
```

I have created a directory in `.bash_login` and called `~/sysadmin1/my_peeps/$DATE`.

Also, inside the `.bash_login` I created two variables which are

```
DATE=$(date +"%m/%d/%y")
TIME=$(date +"%H:%M:%S")
```

Comment: What do you mean you're not sure it works? Does it work? What's in the file? Please give more information. People can't help you if you don't ask a complete question.

Comment: What is `$DATE`? A directory?

Comment: Sorry about that. I have created a directory in .bash_login and called ~/sysadmin1/my_peeps/$DATE. Also, inside the .bash_loggin I created two variables which are:

Comment: Is `w > ${HOME}/${DATE}/${TIME}.users` what you're looking for?

Answer (score 0):

If `$TIME` is not set, then the line becomes

```
w > .users
```

so the output is redirected to a hidden `.users` file. 
You can see it using `ls -a`.

Also note that you need to export variables in `bash` to make them available in child shells:

```
export TIME=$(date +"%H:%M:%S")
```